# "" is an invalid integer lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I have no idea how to fix it

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var conf, adult: Integer;
   pr:real;
begin
    adult:=StrToInt(Edit2.text);
    conf:=StrToInt(Edit3.text);
    pr:=StrToFloat(Edit4.text);
    If Peak1.Checked then
      pr:=(adult*8.95)+(conf*6.45)
    else
    pr:=(adult*7.45)+(conf*5.95);

    Edit4.text:='£'+(FloatToStr(pr));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edit2.clear;
  edit3.clear;
  edit4.clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close
end;
```

I tried to change from StrToInt to FloatToString, I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: What did you do after starting the prog? Did you write something in any of the `Edit` boxes, before you hit `Button1`? If yes, what did you write? Did you read the user's manual for the program? ;)

Comment: The error message is shown when any of the `StrToInt()` or `StrToFloat()` functions try to read an empty `Edit2.text`, `Edit3.text` or `Edit4.text` property. `StrToInt()` or `StrToFloat()` must be given a string, that when evaluated forms an `integer` or `float` value.

Comment: In other words: `0` is a valid Integer, but empty text is neither a valid Integer, nor a valid number. Numbers can't be empty. You surely know that - you just don't understand the error message as that.

Answer (score 2):

The error `"" is an invalid integer` means you are trying to convert an empty string to a number which is impossible and hence the exception.

If you are not sure that the strings actually contain correctly written integers/floats, then use the [TryStrToInt](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/trystrtoint.html) and [TryStrToFloat](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/trystrtofloat.html) functions. These functions do not throw exceptions and instead return a boolean value indicating whether the conversion succeeded — use the results to detect problems with user input.